# Check atribute value from another table using a foreign key in table creation

Tags: sql, validation, foreign-keys, oracle10g, create-table

Is it possible to check the value of an attribute in a different table in table creation? For example I have this table ticket:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket
(
    id_ticket_pk NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    hand_in_date DATE NOT NULL,
    num_clothes NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    deposite NUMBER (8,2) NOT NULL,
    comment VARCHAR2(40),
    tax NUMBER(5,3) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    id_counter_fk1 NUMBER(4),
    id_client_fk2  NUMBER(4),

    CONSTRAINT ticket_id_counter_fk1 
        FOREIGN KEY (id_counter_fk1) REFERENCES empleado(id_employee_pk),
    CONSTRAINT ticket_id_client_fk2 
        FOREIGN KEY(id_client_fk2) REFERENCES client(id_client_pk)
);
```

This table relates to the employee table which has an attribute called type that can be equal to C - for counter, S- for secretary etc... I would like to know if its possible to add a constraint in the creation of the table that verifies that the employee inserted has an employee.type = 'C' where employe.id_pk = ticket.id_counter_fk2. Or do I have to create an external function or client App that manages this?

Comment: Are you asking for a foreign Key that references two remote tables?

Comment: Yess, what I wanted to do was use a constraint  with the foreign key counter, select from employee were employee id = counter id verifying that the type of said employee was C (counter). What I ended up doing was a client app that manages the insertion, deletion and modification of data.

Comment: "has an employee.type = 'C' where employe.id_pk = ticket.id_counter_fk2" is not clear. Please use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. (Then googling it you'd find:) PS There is a common idiom allowing declarative constraint enforcement (hence avoiding a trigger) where you declare a FK on id plus an added (subtype/variant) tag column in ticket with the value 'C' in every row. (Best is computed/generated.) It happens to violate 2NF--as does any computed/generated column that is not a function of a CK--but that's not a problem with proper constraint enforcement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking whether you can use the foreign keying mechanism to ensure that only people with the job title of "counter" can create support tickets.

The short answer is no, you can't have a foreign key on this table that checks the employee table pk for the value given in id_counter_fk1 and enforces that the employee type be C

You could do it several other ways, the most direct being a trigger that prevents the insert if the employee linked is not a C type, but the FK mechanism exists to ensure that a remote record exists or not, not that it exists and has particular properties